# How do I control the taskbar (in the manner I describe) in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, taskbar

Can I pin a window onto the taskbar in Windows XP?

The situation at the moment, is that if I have many programs open, then an up and down arrow appears.

The first group of items:

[image]

The second group:

[image]

A third group(which happens to contain just one):

[image]

If I am viewing Group 1 or 3, then click into my web browser, then the taskbar changes to show Group 2.  If I am viewing Group 2, then click into my browser, then the taskbar stays at group 2.

Is there a way to get the taskbar to stay at whatever group it is showing?

Is there a way to move windows on the taskbar? So if there are a few I want to see right now, I can put them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rearrange programs on the task bar you can use [Taskbar Shuffle](http://nerdcave.webs.com/).

Comment: that's good..  Still though nothing to get the taskbar to stay at whatever group is showing.  I did find another thing one can do, is put the taskbar on the side, then extend width.. it can take a lot more than the taskbar on the bottom without needing a scrollbar.

Comment: Don't know about locking in place, you can try some of the apps that convert taskbar to look like Win7 one. Don't use them so can't say which is good. One other thing to try is VirtuaWin that creates virtual desktops so you can have different apps on different desktops. Taskbar will only show programs that are on the current desktop. LInk: http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/